# How to verify and generate a report ADA compliance in a website

Tags: manual-testing, web-application, web

We have a requirement that a particular website need to be tested for ADA Compliance and we need to generate a report with non compliance and solution to fix that. Any help how to process this verification.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I don't think it's as easy as running a website through a tool and have it tell you whether it's ADA Compliant or not. Take a look at W3's article on '[Web Content Accessibility Guidelines requirements (success criteria) and techniques](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/quickref/)' - you'll need to go through each of the requirements and test for compliance that way.

The article below was taken from a Digital Marketing Agency called [Wakefly](https://www.wakefly.com/blog/ada-compliance-website/) that was returned from a Google search of 'ADA compliance' (which I hadn't heard of until now!)

> The ADA encourages the use of the [Web Content Accessibility
>   Guidelines 2.0 (WCAG)](https://www.w3.org/WAI/standards-guidelines/wcag/) as a guide on how to make your site
>   accessible.

WCAG is organized as 12 guidelines under 4 principles (POUR):

> - **Perceivable**: Web content is made available to the senses – sight, hearing, and/or touch.
> - **Operable**: Interface forms, controls, and navigation are operable.
> - **Understandable**: Content and interface are understandable.
> - **Robust**: Site should work in all environment.

These guidelines and principles conform to WCAG compliance (success criteria) in one of three levels:

> - Level A (must satisfy)
> - Level AA (should satisfy): Makes sites accessible to people with a wider range of disabilities, including the most common barriers
> - Level AAA (may satisfy): Most demanding    level of WCAG compliance

Answer (score 1):

This chapter from official ADA website would probably help you. [This is Website Accessibility Under Title II of the ADA.](https://www.ada.gov/pcatoolkit/chap5toolkit.htm). They state accessibility problems and possible solutions. You can use this as asepcification for your testing.